# Colored output without Perl

Tags: perl

I have a mailing script to send colored output, but I can't use it on a Unix machine as the `MIME::Lite` module is not installed on it.

Can anyone suggest an alternative to get the desired output in color?

```
use MIME::Lite;

my (@page_html, @sujet);

my $file = 'rpt.html';

open my $ifh, '<', $file
     or die "Cannot open '$file' for reading: $!";

local $/ = "";

my $contents = <$ifh>;

close( $ifh );

my $msg = new MIME::Lite;
```

Output:

```
<tr><td>test1</td><td bgcolor=red>NOK</td></tr>    
<tr><td>test2</td><td bgcolor=green>OK</td></tr>    
<tr><td>test3</td><td bgcolor=green>OK</td></tr>
```

`OK` Should be in green

`NOK` should be red

Comment: You should install `MIME::Lite`. It's not hard. But MIME is nothing to do with coloured output.

Comment: Borodin, Not allowed to install..

Comment: You can install it for just your own use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coloured output seems to be a complete red herring (hah!) here. You have a file which you want to send as an attachment to a MIME email.

If you're going to be using Perl, then you need to be in an environment where you can install modules from CPAN. Without CPAN, you're missing most of the power of modern Perl. I suggest that it's worth having whatever discussions you need to have in order to remove that major block to your Perl programming career.

If you really can't install modules into the system libraries, then you can install them into your home directory and use `use lib` or PERL5LIB to adjust the Perl library path as appropriate.

When you've solved the problem of how to use CPAN modules, can we talk about your choice of modules? MIME::Lite [isn't exactly deprecated](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Lite#WAIT!), but there have been better alternatives available for over ten years. Take a look at [Email::Stuffer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Stuffer).

But if you're determined not to have the CPAN module installation discussion, the other approach is to use the command-line program `mailx` to send your message.

```
$ mailx -a rpt.html someone@example.com
```